# Finding PHP Incomplete Object Error?

Tags: php

I got confused with this code

```
<?php

$input = 'O:1:"B":1:{s:6:"secret";s:6:"Got_it";}';
$o = unserialize($input);
//echo $o;  
print_r($o->secret);

?>
```

I have tried to get the $o->secret but it happened this error:

> **Notice:** main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a
>   property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class
>   definition "B" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded
>   *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/mikun/public_html/tested.php on
>   **line 6**

Please help me to sovle it!

Comment: It appears that you are trying to unserialize an object of class `B`. Have you defined class `B` anywhere?

Comment: This is a serialized version of a `B` object.  Make sure `class B` was included first.

Comment: It's telling you what's wrong, that's a bad serialized string. Where are you generating that from? I don't see a "B" class anywhere.

Comment: @RobW: It's not a "bad string", it's just referencing an undefined class.

Comment: the error message tells you exactly what's wrong AND how to fix it ...

Answer (score 4):

Your code is unserializing an object of the class `B`.

```
$input = 'O:1:"B":1:{s:6:"secret";s:6:"Got_it";}';
               ^
```

PHP cannot unserialize the object unless it knows what class `B` is supposed to look  like and as a result needs a definition first. In this instance you need to specify a class definition for `B` **before** the `unserialize()` call. For example:

```
class B {
    public $secret;
    public $param2;
};

$input = 'O:1:"B":1:{s:6:"secret";s:6:"Got_it";}';
$o = unserialize($input);
//$o is now an instance of class B
print_r($o->secret); //prints "Got_it"
```

Comment: Hi guys, for example, I got this simple code:

    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="serial">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    
    if (isset($_POST['serial'])) {
        
        $serial = $_POST['serial'];
        $o = unserialize($serial);
    
        if ($o) {
            
            echo $o->secret;
        }
    }
    
    ?>

What would I do to get the $o->secret ?

Comment: @omgpwned: Why are you letting users submit serialized PHP data?  That's a really bad idea.  It's not safe.

Comment: @omgpwned: Where is this data coming from?  Where are the users getting it from?  What is `class B`?  What is your *real* goal here?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: I just study it on my own and I wonder how it will react to my serialized input.

Comment: @omgpwned: Where is this being serialized from?  You need to make sure that `class B` is loaded when you unserialize it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Is there any other way to input a serialized data and make the $o->secret printed? sorry if my question seems stupid.

Comment: @omgpwned: Serialize a "normal" object, not a `B` object.  Like: `$o = new stdClass;  $o->secret = "Got_it";  echo serialize($o);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a B class to structure your data you can fix the serialized string by editing the class B to be stdClass. To do so you would change

`O:1:"B":1:{s:6:"secret";s:6:"Got_it";}`

to

`O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:6:"secret";s:6:"Got_it";}`

You'll notice that `O:1` becomes `O:8`. That is telling php that the object name is now eight  characters long `stdClass`.